# createOrReplaceTempView is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, hbase, rdd

I am using **hadoop 2.7.2 , hbase 1.4.9, spark 2.2.0, scala 2.11.8 and java 1.8** .
I run this command whithout having any error:

```
val Patterns_fromHbase = mimic_PatternsFromHbase.mapPartitions(f=> f.map(row1 => (Bytes.toString(row1._2.getRow), Bytes.toString(row1._2.getValue(Bytes.toBytes("sepsiscategories"),Bytes.toBytes("subject_id")))))).toDF("id","subject_id")
```

Then I run this command :

```
mimic_PatternsFromHbase.createOrReplaceTempView("subject_id_table")
```

and I just have this error:

> :57: error: value createOrReplaceTempView is not a member of
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.ImmutableBytesWritable,
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result)]
>          mimic_PatternsFromHbase.createOrReplaceTempView("subject_id_table")

what is the cause of this error and how to fix it please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my fault, it is a fault of bad attention.
in the place to call createOrReplaceView method by calling them by **Patterns_fromHbase** I called her by **mimic_PatternsFromHbase**